# Xとも言えるY and であるが故に at the end of a sentence

Tags: grammar

I think this could be translated as

Y which could be called X

How do I understand this sentence though.

> だが、ここに世界は終わらずにいる。
>   **我々が築いた世界像は、星が思い描いた世界像を遥かに凌駕する強靭さを誇ったが故に。**―――――朱色の月は涙する。
>   長い闘争になると悲嘆する。
>   だが滅び新月になろうとも終わりではない。
>   何故ならこの地上全ての生物が敵に回ろうと。
>   **一つ、絶対とも言える時間だけは、彼の協力者であるが故に―――**
>
> But the world here is not over.
>   The reason is that the image of the world we drew is proud of the strenght that came from surpassing by far the world the stars imagined.  (or "The reason is that the image of the world we drew is proud of the strenght through which it surpassed by far the world the stars imagined.) 
>   The creamson moon sheds tears.
>   If/When it ends up with a fight it will grieve.
>   But when the perishing new moon will come it will not be the end.
>   That is because every animal on the land will become an enemy.
>   Because one reason is that, Absolute which could only be called time, it's his accomplice.

I am not really sure about that bold part.

I looked up on the internet and found this examples:

a) 奇跡的とも言える立ち直りを見せる
Make an almost miracolous comeback

b) 翌朝、まだ早朝とも言える時間にタウンハウスを発ち、私を乗せた車はデヴォンシャーに向けて、M1をただひたすらに北へ目指す。
The next morning, at a time which could still be called very early in the morning I left my town house. The car I was on was directed to Devon going north following the M1.

I had also trouble because of であるが故に and found out it's just a different way of simly using 故に. 
At the end of a sentence it means "it is the reason" if I understand it correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, ～が故に is a literary and a bit archaic expression that means "because ～". In archaic Japanese, the dictionary form of a verb could be directly connected with が without any nominalizers (cf. 逃げるが勝ち). A modern equivalent is ～ことが理由で.

> - 彼は強すぎたが故に、誰も彼に戦いを挑まなかった。
>     Since he was so strong, no one dared to challenge him.
> - 誰も彼に戦いを挑まなかった。彼は強すぎたが故に。(rhetoric word order)
>     No one dared to challenge him. For he was so strong.

AともいえるB = "B which can also be called A"

絶対とも言える時間 = time which can also be called the absolute (existence).

If I translate the last sentence literally: "For one, it's because nothing but time, which can be called the absolute, is his ally...". You can paraphrase it as something like "Because time is the absolute existence, and time is the last thing that will betray him."

Answer (score 2):

#### X とも言える Y

You're right that とも言える literally means "could (also) be called". However, in this specific disposition it often begets extra connotations that could be translated into "Y, virtually equals to X" or "Y, fully deserves the name of X". This phrasing is mostly seen in literary language.

と言ってもいい has a similar usage too.

#### が故に

が故に has nothing different than 故に, but only a bit more archaic, therefore a bit more elevated in style. This が actually means の, が and の were used right opposite of how they are today in Classical Japanese. Strictly speaking, が appear in your example are grammatically redundant, but nobody seriously cares about classical grammar :P

---

Aside from the question, I see you've miserably tossed about by the author's punctuation-happy writing style. If allow me to use your translation mutatis mutandis:

> But the world here is not over.
>   **Inasmuch as** the image of the world we drew **boasted** the strength which by far surpassed **that of** the world the stars imagined.
>   The crimson moon sheds tears.
>   **Grieving that it will break into a long strife**.
>   But when **it will perish (=wane?) into** the new moon it will not be the end.
>   That is because, **may all life** on the land become enemies...
>   **The time, the one nearly absolute, alone** is his accomplice.